# TypeORM automatic nested JSON when joining table in getRawMany

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I got problem with TypeORM return here.

My query code :

```
const data = await MatchDetail.createQueryBuilder('md')
  .select([
    'team.*',
    'sum(md.totalPoint) as teamTotalPoint',
  ])
  .innerJoin('md.team', 'team')
  .groupBy('md.teamId')
  .getRawMany();
```

I was expecting the return will be like :

```
{
  team:{
    ...teamData
  },
  teamTotalPoint: numberHere
}
```

since the `getMany()` method have automaticly nested JSON when joining a relation.

but I got this result

```
{
  ...teamData
  teamTotalPoint: numberHere
}
```

How can I map the rest `...teamData` into a nested JSON `team` as I expected using typeORM method? or I should map it manually?